# Get exception: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type Booking.Repositories.DriverRepository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I know that I need to register the `DriverRepository` service before using it.

Here is what I did:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDriverRepository, DriverRepository>();
```

Now in my `DriverAccountsModel` class:

```cs
public class DriverAccountsModel : PageModel
{
    public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }
    public IDriverRepository DriverRepository { get; }

    public DriverAccountsModel(IHttpContextAccessor 
        httpContextAccessor,
        DriverRepository driverRepository)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        DriverRepository = driverRepository;
    }
    public List<DriverAccounts> results;
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var results = DriverRepository.GetAll();

        return Redirect("DriverAccounts");
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost(int id, Models.DriverAccounts driverAccounts)
    {
        return Redirect("DriverAccounts");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The constructor should retrieve the `IDriverRepository` (interface) service but not the `DriverRepository` (class).

```cs
public DriverAccountsModel(
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    IDriverRepository driverRepository)
{
    HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    DriverRepository = driverRepository;
}
```